# Check which polygon of one layer contains a polygon in another layer

Tags: python, polygon, shapefile

I have a shapefile with two layers (sets of cpg, dbf, prj, shp, shx files).
L1 represents the sub-area of a city and L2 represents specific buildings.

One of the attributes of L1 is the name of the sub-area (NAME)
One of the attributes of L2 is the postal code of the building (A_PSTCD).

My task is to create a DataFrame that will have a list of unique pairs "NAME/A_PSTCD".
For this I need to match L1 to L2 and then extract the relevant fields.

I am very new to shapefiles, although I have some experience with python. Any advice on how to approach this proble would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find a solution on my own:

1.Import libraries

```
import geopandas as gpd
```

2.Load the buildings file

```
buildings_polys = gpd.read_file('.../buildings.shp')
```

3.Load the areas file

```
polygons_areas = gpd.read_file('.../areas.shp')
```

4.Find buildings centroid

```
buildings_points = buildings_polys.copy()
buildings_points['geometry'] = buildings_points['geometry'].centroid
```

5.Check what area the building is in

```
i = 0
for area in areas:
    i+=1
    print('{} of {}'.format(i, len(areas)), area)
    buildings_points[area] = np.where(buildings_points['geometry'].within(dictionary[area]), 1, 0)
```

This will create a dataframe of buildings, with a bunch of columns (the full list of areas) that will have either 1 or 0 depending on whether the building is in that area.

You could also do something like (instead of the last line in step 5:

```
buildings_points['area_of_building'] = np.where(buildings_points['geometry'].within(dictionary[area]), area, 0)
```

To get a single column where you will have the name of the area.